# Список - результат функции

Tags: python, функции, список

Моя функция создает список.

```
def make_lists():
    my_list = [1,2,3,4]
    return (my_list)
```

Мне нужно ее зациклить с временным периодом и условием: выводить список (результат функции) если он не равен предыдущему.

Такой вариант:

```
all_lists = [make_lists() for _ in range (5)]
```

не совсем подходит, как туда прописать условие, типа:

```
make_lists [x] != make_lists [x-1]
```

Я не хотел бы помещать это все в ту же функцию. (делать цикл внутри функции)

Comment: Возможно, через генератор и смогли бы сделать через оператор `:=` (python 3.8), но тут сомневаюсь. А чем плоха функция с циклом внутри?

Comment: Что выводить, если результат окажется равен предыдущему? Проверяем только с предыдущим или вообще на все, которые были раньше?

Comment: Проверять только с предыдущим, если есть отличие - выводить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через переменную цикла:

```
old_item = None
for item in all_lists:
    if item != old_item:
        print item
    old_item = item
    # sleep()
```